# QGIS image downloading

Tags: geotiff-tiff, image, resolution, download

I want to download image from QGIS. What should i write in Resolution setting(2 dialog boxes horizontal and vertical)? What do they mean?
[image]

Comment: Corresponding place in the documentation is https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/fi/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html?highlight=save%20raster#id2

Answer (score 2):

You can keep resolution of the input raster and so the resolution of the output raster will not be changed.
Otherwise:
x = the width of the cells in the output raster
y = the height of the cells in the output raster

The grid cells cannot be zero. As an example x = 2m and y =2m, the cell is 2x2m. Of course, it always depends on your source material how useful the values are.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand. What do you mean? if i leave boxes empty i will have an error: "Cannot write raster. Error code: data source creation
Cannot create new dataset  1.tif:
Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero."

Comment: I have edited the answer above.